# Different deviation path but same wallet address

Tags: wallet

I transferred some SOL from my Solflare wallet to my Keystone but its not showing. I can see that wallet address on Solscan with the balance but it looks like its a different deviation path from my SOL Keystone address although the wallet address is the same. How can I access it if Keystone are not showing the SOL even though the wallet address is the same? Keystone have not been very forthcoming.

Comment: same thing happened to me with a lot of money. whats going on here